# How do I specify the filesystem_arn for the aws datasync module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Edit: I just noticed the error seems to be about the *filesystem* arn I have specified and not the subnet arn so I've edited the question. Good grief.

I'm trying to define an `aws_datasync_location_efs` object in Terraform using the example [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/datasync_location_efs#attributes-reference)

The datasync location wants a `efs_file_system_arn` so this seems like it should work but why am I getting this error?

> Error: creating DataSync Location EFS: ValidationException: 1
> validation error detected: Value
> 'arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:us-east-1::file-system/fs-0d5b67a50ea988fb6'
> at 'efsFilesystemArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must
> satisfy regular expression pattern:
> ^arn:(aws|aws-cn|aws-us-gov|aws-iso|aws-iso-b):elasticfilesystem:[a-z-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:file-system/fs-[0-9a-f]{8,40}$
> status code: 400, request id:
> e5f906d9-068b-4250-a9d7-63dd5dc813d1 with
> aws_datasync_location_efs.example, on efs.tf line 71, in resource
> "aws_datasync_location_efs" "example": 71: resource
> "aws_datasync_location_efs" "example" {

private subnet variables in `variables.tf`

```
variable "my_private_subnets" {
  type         = list
  description  = "private subnet within vpc cidr block"
  default      = ["10.0.100.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24"]
}
```

the vpc in `main.tf`

```
module "vpc" {
  source                = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  name                  = "${var.my_project}-vpc"
  cidr                  = "${var.my_cidr}"

  azs                   = ["${var.my_region}a", "${var.my_region}b"]
  private_subnets       = [for subnet in var.my_private_subnets: subnet]
  public_subnets        = [for subnet in var.my_public_subnets:  subnet]
  
  enable_nat_gateway    = true
  enable_dns_hostnames  = true
  enable_dns_support    = true
}
```

my datasync declaration in `efs.tf`

```
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "my_target1" {
   file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.my_efs.id
   subnet_id       = module.vpc.private_subnets[0]
   security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_efs-sg.id]
}

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "my_target2" {
   file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.my_efs.id
   subnet_id       = module.vpc.private_subnets[1]
   security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_efs-sg.id]
}

resource "aws_datasync_location_efs" "example" {
  efs_file_system_arn   = aws_efs_mount_target.my_target1.file_system_arn

  ec2_config {
    security_group_arns = [aws_security_group.my_efs-sg.arn]
    subnet_arn          = module.vpc.public_subnet_arns[0]
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably bug in aws provider. Please make issue on github about that.

Comment: Issue submitted. Any ideas for a work-around? I tried a `data` source on the filesystem or target (don't recall which) but resulting `arn` threw the same error.